# How to categorize(sort) a specific date based on an already made pandas date range series?

Tags: python, date, pandas

I have made a list of date series:

```
import pandas as pd

daterange2016 = pd.date_range("2016-04-25 00:00:00", "2016-04-29 21:00:00", freq="30min")
```

However, I want a function to get a date time and know which interval does the time belongs to. I don't want to change the intervals. How can I do this?

something like (here is a pseudocode):

```
def datetimesorter(givendate):
    if givendate:
       df['pd_time_interval_that_givendate_belongs_to'] = givendate
```

Thanks in advance for the help

update: I came up with this, it works but I won't delete the question just in case it helps someone

```
def daterangefinder(datetime):
    for intervals in daterange2016:
        if intervals <= datetime < intervals+1:
            return intervals
        else:
            pass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC you can try:

```
import pandas as pd

daterange2016 = pd.date_range("2016-04-25 00:00:00", "2016-04-25 05:00:00", freq="30min")
print daterange2016
DatetimeIndex(['2016-04-25 00:00:00', '2016-04-25 00:30:00',
               '2016-04-25 01:00:00', '2016-04-25 01:30:00',
               '2016-04-25 02:00:00', '2016-04-25 02:30:00',
               '2016-04-25 03:00:00', '2016-04-25 03:30:00',
               '2016-04-25 04:00:00', '2016-04-25 04:30:00',
               '2016-04-25 05:00:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='30T')

df = pd.DataFrame(daterange2016, columns=['d1'])

df['d2']= df.d1.shift(-1)
print df
                    d1                  d2
0  2016-04-25 00:00:00 2016-04-25 00:30:00
1  2016-04-25 00:30:00 2016-04-25 01:00:00
2  2016-04-25 01:00:00 2016-04-25 01:30:00
3  2016-04-25 01:30:00 2016-04-25 02:00:00
4  2016-04-25 02:00:00 2016-04-25 02:30:00
5  2016-04-25 02:30:00 2016-04-25 03:00:00
6  2016-04-25 03:00:00 2016-04-25 03:30:00
7  2016-04-25 03:30:00 2016-04-25 04:00:00
8  2016-04-25 04:00:00 2016-04-25 04:30:00
9  2016-04-25 04:30:00 2016-04-25 05:00:00
10 2016-04-25 05:00:00                 NaT
```

```
date = pd.to_datetime('2016-04-25 02:15:08')
print date
2016-04-25 02:15:08

print (df.d1 < date) & (df.d2 > date)
0     False
1     False
2     False
3     False
4      True
5     False
6     False
7     False
8     False
9     False
10    False
dtype: bool

print df[(df.d1 < date) & (df.d2 > date)].d1
4   2016-04-25 02:00:00
Name: d1, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

If you need add `date` to new column `d3` use [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df.loc[(df.d1 < date) & (df.d2 > date), 'd3'] =  date
print df
                    d1                  d2                  d3
0  2016-04-25 00:00:00 2016-04-25 00:30:00                 NaT
1  2016-04-25 00:30:00 2016-04-25 01:00:00                 NaT
2  2016-04-25 01:00:00 2016-04-25 01:30:00                 NaT
3  2016-04-25 01:30:00 2016-04-25 02:00:00                 NaT
4  2016-04-25 02:00:00 2016-04-25 02:30:00 2016-04-25 02:15:08
5  2016-04-25 02:30:00 2016-04-25 03:00:00                 NaT
6  2016-04-25 03:00:00 2016-04-25 03:30:00                 NaT
7  2016-04-25 03:30:00 2016-04-25 04:00:00                 NaT
8  2016-04-25 04:00:00 2016-04-25 04:30:00                 NaT
9  2016-04-25 04:30:00 2016-04-25 05:00:00                 NaT
10 2016-04-25 05:00:00                 NaT                 NaT
```

Comment: Please check my solution. Thanks.